# Removing object from camera

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

I developed a program and a module in this has lots of shape classes. Consider a shape class such as a rectangle that I have here and a `draw` function that is continously called from my class.

```
virtual void draw()
{
if(State == HOVERING || State == CLOSED){                   
rec.draw(playerContainer);
gluLookAt(lookAtPoint);
}
else if(State == OPENING)
{
glPushMatrix();         
glTranslatef(Tweenable3D::pos.x,Tweenable3D::pos.y,Tweenable3D::pos.z);
glRotatef(Tweenable3D::xRotation,-1,0,0);                        
glTranslatef(-Tweenable3D::pos.y,-Tweenable3D::pos.y,-Tweenable3D::pos.z);
rectShape.draw(Tweenable3D::pos.x, Tweenable3D::pos.y, Tweenable3D::width, Tweenable3D::height);
glTranslatef(ofGetWidth()/2, ofGetHeight()/2,0);
glPopMatrix();
}
else
{
setPosition(vidPlayerFinalPosition);
rectShape.draw(vidPlayerFinalPosition, vidPlayerFinalWidth, vidPlayerFinalHeight);
ofCircle(vidPlayerFinalPosition, 30);
ofVec3f looks(0,0,0);
lookAt(looks);
}
}
```

The `Tweenable3D` used in the second is nothing but kind of interpolated values for my animations. I am doing animations of rotations, translations and others in such a way.

The catch here is that my shape is inside a camera at the beginning. For the second if condition I have to perform some animations as I wrote above. However, when I include a camera in my program, it messes up and translates the coordinates to center of the screen (my initial coordinates are at top left)

I have to do my own translation to correct this camera translation or try world to screen/screen to world etc.
I was just wondering if there's way I could some how get this object out of the camera, do my animations and stuff and later in other if conditions also put it back in the camera when required. It might not be correct to say that the object is out of the camera (probably some mathematical function already there would help in getting that effect)

Answer (score 0):

What's that *camera* you're talking about? OpenGL doesn't have a "camera". What's a "camera" and what's not, is completely up to you and the semantics your code implements.

I think your mistake is, that you confuse OpenGL for a scene graph, which it is not. In fixed function mode it has a number of matrices and it just throws individual points, lines and trianges to the screen based on some numbers you feed it and it processes through those matrices. There's no scene, there are no objects, there's no object hierachy.

---

Also what do you mean by "object is in the camera"?